# Internal working of sprintf

Tags: c++, c, printf

i am using sprintf like this

```
sprintf(cTmpBuf, "%0*lu",targetPrecision,ulFraction);
```

before this i was using like this

```
sprintf(cTmpBuf, "%06lu", ulFraction);
```

now that i know it pick  targetPrecision's value and put it to * but i want to know internal thing happen behind it

Comment: Do you want to know how it's implemented?

Comment: Both calls look the same to me unless my eyes are deceiving me?!!!

Comment: sorry @RedSerpent the second one is                                sprintf(cTmpBuf, "%06lu", ulFraction);

Comment: @vivekgaur: Don't add a comment; just edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know how it's implemented, there's no magic; it's just another argument processed using `<stdarg.h>`. Very roughly, it'll be something like:

```
prec = -1;
⋮
if (*cp == '*') {
  prec = va_arg(ap, int);
  cp++;
}
```

Comment: ap took the value i pass and then apply it?

Comment: It does what I showed. Upon seeing the `*`, the function decides to interpret the next argument as an integer used to specify the precision. It may help to understand that the regular arguments are processed in exactly the same manner. E.g., if the function sees `%g`, it will do something like `double d = va_arg(ap, double); /* …format the double… */`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question but in string formatting using `*` makes you control the formatting width. So in the first call the formatting width is determined by the value of `targetPrecision`.

In the second call the formatting width is fixed to 6 digits.

As for the actual internals of `sprintf`. you can refer to @Marcelo Cantos's answer.

Check this [`link`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) for formatting parameters.